# Multiple definitions error: one in my file and one in the moc file.

Tags: qt4, multiple-definition-error, moc

I have a class called FindAndReplaceBar, whose implementation is this:

```
#include "FindAndReplaceBar.h"
#include <QLabel>
#include <QPushButton>
#include <QGridLayout>
#include <QTextDocument>
#include <QLineEdit>

FindAndReplaceBar::FindAndReplaceBar(QObject *parent) :
    QToolBar(NULL)
{
    lblFind         = new QLabel("Find: ",this);
    lblReplace      = new QLabel("Replace",this);

    ledtFind        = new QLineEdit(this);
    ledtReplace     = new QLineEdit(this);

    QPixmap next(":/res/resources/next.gif");
    QPixmap previous(":/res/resources/previous.gif");
    QPixmap close(":/res/resources/close_icon.gif");

    btnFindNext     = new QPushButton(QIcon(next),"",this);
    btnFindPrevious = new QPushButton(QIcon(previous),"",this);
    btnClose        = new QPushButton(QIcon(close),"",this);

    btnReplace      = new QPushButton("Replace",this);
    btnReplaceAll   = new QPushButton("Replace All",this);

    btnFindNext->setFlat(true);
    btnFindPrevious->setFlat(true);
    btnClose->setFlat(true);
    btnReplace->setFlat(true);
    btnReplaceAll->setFlat(true);

    lytFindAndReplaceBar        = new QGridLayout(this);

    lytFindAndReplaceBar->addWidget(lblFind,0,0,1,1);
    lytFindAndReplaceBar->addWidget(ledtFind,0,1,1,2);
    lytFindAndReplaceBar->addWidget(btnFindPrevious,0,3,1,1);
    lytFindAndReplaceBar->addWidget(btnFindNext,0,4,1,1);

    lytFindAndReplaceBar->addWidget(lblReplace,0,5,1,1);
    lytFindAndReplaceBar->addWidget(ledtReplace,0,6,1,2);
    lytFindAndReplaceBar->addWidget(btnReplace,0,8,1,1);
    lytFindAndReplaceBar->addWidget(btnReplaceAll,0,9,1,1);

    this->setLayout(lytFindAndReplaceBar);

    connect(btnFindNext,SIGNAL(clicked()),this,SIGNAL(findNext()));
    connect(btnFindPrevious,SIGNAL(pressed()),this,SIGNAL(findPrevious()));
    connect(btnClose,SIGNAL(pressed()),this,SLOT(close()));
    connect(btnReplace,SIGNAL(pressed()),this,SIGNAL(replace()));
    connect(btnReplaceAll,SIGNAL(pressed()),this,SIGNAL(replaceAll()));

    this->setStyleSheet("QToolBar{background: qlineargradient(x1:0,x2:0,y1:0,y2:1,stop:0 #fffaf0,stop:0.3 #fdf5e6)} QLineEdit{border-radius:4px;padding:2px;}");
}

void FindAndReplaceBar::findNext()
{
    emit find(0);
}

void FindAndReplaceBar::findPrevious()
{
    emit find(QTextDocument::FindBackward);
}

void FindAndReplaceBar::replace()
{
    emit replace(false);
}

void FindAndReplaceBar::replaceAll()
{
    emit replace(true);
}

QString FindAndReplaceBar::searchTerm()
{
    return this->ledtFind->text();
}

QString FindAndReplaceBar::replaceTerm()
{
    return this->ledtReplace->text();
}

void FindAndReplaceBar::setSearchFieldText(const QString & searchFieldText)
{
    this->ledtFind->setText(searchFieldText);
}

void FindAndReplaceBar::setReplaceFieldText(const QString & replaceFieldText)
{
    this->ledtReplace->setText(replaceFieldText);
}
```

When I run the program I get problems of multiple definitions of the functions:

`findNext()`, `findPrevious()`, `replace()`, `replaceAll()`.

The other definition is made in the moc_FindAndReplaceBar.cpp file.
I'm not sure what the problem so I don't know how to fix it! I would really appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Try to do a full, clean build. Sometimes things get out of sync.

Comment: I did. I got a dialog that the moc_FindAndReplaceBar had been removed and would I like to save it with a different name. I thought renaming it might create bigger problems so I just clicked on 'Save'

Comment: Looks like your build system is confused. Remove the moc files so that they get regenerated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Judging by your connect calls (signal to signal), I assume if we look at your header file, you will have declared `findNext(), findPrevious(), replace(), replaceAll()` as **signals**, but **you must not implement signals** - they just need to be declared in the header.

From the Qt docs on [signals](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html#signals)

> Signals are automatically generated by the moc and must not be
>   implemented in the .cpp file. They can never have return types (i.e.
>   use void).

Comment: That's precisely what I did. Thanks, I can take it from here :)

Comment: I just ran into this as well. An easy mistake when you declare the signals first, then copy & paste to another class and forget to change signals to slots :)